# TYPO3 8.7.x lib.parseFunc ATagParams

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x, fluid-styled-content

Since TYPO3 8.7.x it seems that:

```
lib.parseFunc.tags.link.typolink.ATagParams =style="style="color:#000; text-decoration:underline;font-size:16px;"
```

dosen't exist no more in fluid styled content. Works in 7.6. Also

```
lib.parseFunc.tags.a.typolink.ATagParams.data = style="color:#000; text-decoration:underline;font-size:16px;"
```

retained in frontend.

Related issue but marked as solved: [forge.typo3.org](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/79896)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `lib.parseFunc.tags.link` does not work anymore since the "link"-tag for RTE placed internal links has been replaced by normal `<a href="t3://anything">` links.

Your possible mistake is that you want to change the ATagParams statically. `.data` is expecting some data to read from. You need to empty the `.data` function first because it takes precedence. Then you can set the ATagParams statically.

Please try it like this:

```
lib.parseFunc.tags.a.typolink.ATagParams.data >    
lib.parseFunc.tags.a.typolink.ATagParams = style="color:#000; text-decoration:underline;font-size:16px;"
```

***Please note that this will affect all links!***

Comment: Aha, thx. you save my day and yes for sure, it's just for a newletter template